# Composite matrices in Numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

Lets say I have four matrices A, B, C and D, and I want to combine them together into one new matrix for computation: 
$$
\left( \begin{matrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
How can I do this in Numpy? The only thing I can think of now is to loop through each element in every matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are commonly called *block matrices*. You can create them with [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), and [`block`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.block.html).